# How to match single face image with list of images in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to compare a single face image with list of face images stored in firestore. but the MatchFacesRequest allows only two image to be compared. first new image and second already stored.
here is the list of employees of snapshot data that I want to compare

```
List<Empl> emp =  snapshot.data!.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList();
```

here image1 is latest image need to compare with list of images and image2 which should be the list of emp images.

```
createButton(
      "Match",
      () {
        var image2 = Regula.MatchFacesImage();

        image2.bitmap = emp[0].imageBase64;
        image2.identifier = emp[0].name;
        image2.imageType = 1;

        setState(() => _similarity = "Processing...");
        var request = Regula.MatchFacesRequest();
        request.images = [image1, image2];

        Regula.FaceSDK.matchFaces(jsonEncode(request)).then(
          (value) {
            var response =
                Regula.MatchFacesResponse.fromJson(
                    json.decode(value));
            Regula.FaceSDK
                    .matchFacesSimilarityThresholdSplit(
                        jsonEncode(response!.detections),
                        0.75)
                .then(
              (str) {
                var split = Regula
                        .MatchFacesSimilarityThresholdSplit
                    .fromJson(json.decode(str));

                setState(
                  () => _similarity =
                      split!.matchedFaces.isNotEmpty
                          ? ((split.matchedFaces[0]!
                                          .similarity! *
                                      100)
                                  .toStringAsFixed(2) +
                              "%")
                          : "error",
                );
                // debugPrint(
                //     ' image index : ${split!.matchedFaces[0]!.first!.imageIndex!}');
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
),
```

I'm using Regula `flutter_face_api` [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_face_api) but this is not properly documented. [here](https://docs.regulaforensics.com/develop/face-sdk/mobile/match-faces/) is the documentation for face matching. but for only single image not for a list of images.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the images you're compairing to the list of images in request:

```
var request = new Regula.MatchFacesRequest();
request.images = [image1, image2, image3];
```

after that you can just check for the matching faces:

```
FaceSDK.matchFacesSimilarityThresholdSplit(jsonEncode(response.results), 0.75).then((splitResponse) {
    var split = Regula.MatchFacesSimilarityThresholdSplit.fromJson(json.decode(splitResponse));
    // ... check split.matchedFaces for the matched faces.
    // ... check split.unmatchedFaces for the matched faces.
});
```

That will result in two list of MatchFaces like this :
[image]

I, actually, change the oficial example for three images in a GIST, of course if you'll need more information about them, yo just need to work around the loop at the response.

```
var request = new Regula.MatchFacesRequest();
    request.images = [image1, image2, image3];
    Regula.FaceSDK.matchFaces(jsonEncode(request)).then((value) {
      var response = Regula.MatchFacesResponse.fromJson(json.decode(value));
      Regula.FaceSDK.matchFacesSimilarityThresholdSplit(
              jsonEncode(response!.results), 0.75)
          .then((str) {
        var split = Regula.MatchFacesSimilarityThresholdSplit.fromJson(
            json.decode(str));
        setState(() {
          if (split!.matchedFaces.length > 0) {
            _similarity = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < split.matchedFaces.length; i++) {
              _similarity +=
                  "${i + 1}. ${(split.matchedFaces[i]!.similarity! * 100).toStringAsFixed(2)} % \n";
            }
          } else {
            _similarity = "error";
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

[Full main.dart GIST here](https://gist.github.com/AlejoCumpa/0533b50b373c7154cb3f1be178802229)

Comment: First thanks  Alejandro.Can you please inform me if images 2 , 3 and so on belong to another list of class Data. Then how can we manage altogether in a single request list. I want to compare image 1 with list of Employee Images

Comment: @hafeezrana of course, you can compare a whole list of images. Nonetheless, that method would compare every image with every image and with return you a List of matchedFaces  with 2 MatchFacesComparedFace parameters : first and second where you can identify the images that result in that comparison.

Comment: However, if you want to compare 1 image to a list of other images where only 1 would match. I suggest you to create a much bigger loop to hold the method and compare two images until  you find the result and in that case break the loop.